# Explicit setter for properties within custom object

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I would like to have an explicit setter for my custom object:

Character class

```
public class CharacterModel
{
  public int HP { get; set; }
  public int MP { get; set; }
}
```

Main.razor

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="Character.HP" />
<input type="text" @bind-value="Character.MP" />

@code {
  private CharacterModel character;
  public CharacterModel Character
  {
    get => character;
    set 
    {
      character = value;
      // Do something else
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that currently the setter within code doesn't run because it's calling the HP and MP setters. Is there a way to call the setter within code when I change HP and MP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No. Since you bind to `Character.HP` and `Character.MP`, you are not changing the property `Character` but instead the model binding only changes that object’s values directly. The same would be true if you did something like this:

```
// setter is called for this:
this.Character = new CharacterModel();

// setter is not called for this:
this.Character.HP = 100;
this.Character.MP = 50;
```

The reason for this is because it is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
// getter is used to retrieve object:
var character = this.Character;

// only operates on a local reference:
character.HP = 100;
character.MP = 50;
```

If you need to find out when a property of the character model is changed, then you could follow the approach that is usually used in MVVM setups. You could have the `CharacterModel` implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netstandard-2.0), having it notify interested parties of property changes:

```
public class CharacterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _hp;
    public int HP
    {
        get => _hp;
        set
        {
            _hp = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _mp;
    public int MP
    {
        get => _mp;
        set
        {
            _mp = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")  
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Yes, this unfortunately adds a lot of bloat to your model type but on the plus side it is now fully reactive. So you can subscribe to changes to its properties:

```
private CharacterModel character;
public CharacterModel Character
{
    get => character;
    set 
    {
        // nothing to do if the value hasn’t changed
        if (character == value)
            return;

        // remove existing event handler
        if (character != null)
            character.PropertyChanged -= HandlePropertyChanged;

        // store new value
        character = value;

        // add event handler
        if (character != null)
            character.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(CharacterModel.HP))
    {
        // HP has changed, do something
        InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            highlightHealthPotion = Character.HP < 20;
            StateHasChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement the code, but `character?.PropertyChanged -= HandlePropertyChanged` gives an error (The event can only appear on the left hand side of -= or +=) and `character.PropertyChanged -=` throws a NullReferenceException, do you know why that is?

Comment: Oh right, you cannot do `character?.PropertyChanged +=` something. I replaced it in my code with explicit null checks. Sorry about that!